# Lean 4 Importing into VSCode

Tags: lean4, lean-mathlib

I am working on Lean4 for a class project. I want to import some of mathlib4, but I keep getting "unknown package". I got Lean4 through the VSCode extension on Windows. How do I import packages?

Update: I've gotten git to work and I've managed to fork Mathlib. I used lake to set up a project, and now I'm having issues using import... anyone know how to help?

Update: I got it figured out. Should I share?

Comment: See here: https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib4#using-mathlib4-as-a-dependency. (In particular see the end about if you already have a project and what to use mathlib 4 as a dependency.)

Comment: As the question stands, it's quite uninformative ("There's a student with a problem."). I would recommend that you not only share the solution, but also what was confusing to you.

Comment: I'm new to stackexchange so sorry if writing this counts as 'necro' or is in some other way inappropiate. Could you please share how you managed to import mathlib4? I'm having the same problem you were having. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @blackbirdsr Where are you in the process? Have you set up lean with VS Code?

Comment: @blackbirdsr Here's how I set up a project: In a terminal go to the folder you want to create your project folder my_project inside. Run `lake +leanprover/lean4:nightly-2023-02-04 new my_project math`. The `math` keyword adds mathlib4 to the dependencies of your project, so that you can use import Mathlib in your project files. Go inside the my_project folder and run `lake update`, then `lake exe cache get`, and then `mkdir MyProject`. Run VS Code by running `code .` and make sure you are in my_project. The .lean files for your project should go in the MyProject folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I go about setting up a project. This information can be found in the Lean documentation. In a terminal go to the folder you want to create your project in. We'll call this project `my_project`. In your terminal run

```
lake +leanprover/lean4:nightly-2023-02-04 new my_project math
```

The date here doesn't need to be changed. The `math` keyword adds mathlib4 to the dependencies of the project so that you can import Mathlib in your project files.

Go inside the `my_project` folder and run `lake update`, then `lake exe cache get`, and then `mkdir MyProject`. Launch VS Code by writing `code .` and make sure you are in `my_project`. The .lean files for your project should go in the MyProject folder.

The documentation is [here](https://leanprover-community.github.io/install/project.html).

Comment: Can you also provide a link to the relevant documentation?  Give how much Lean 4 is still in flux, it may change in the future and it is good to have a stable link to the latest instructions.

Comment: @JasonRute I read your profile... How does computability relate to analysis? I am a pure mathematician at heart. Documentation added btw.